# Date conversion in Hive

Tags: sql, function, date, hive, converters

I want to convert 7 char date format(YYYYDDD) into 8 character date format(DDMMYYYY). Can any one know the function?

example:- 2018001 -- 01012018(January 1st)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Use **unix_timestamp** function and match the incoming format then use **from_unixtime** function to change the write format.

```
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2018001 ','yyyyddd'),'ddMMyyyy');
+-----------+--+
|    _c0    |
+-----------+--+
| 01012018  |
+-----------+--+
```